# Doubt in the definition of closed subvarieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand this definition in Fulton's algebraic curves:

[image]

In order to be $Y$ a variety, $\overline Y$ has to be an irreducible algebraic set of $\mathbb P^{n_1}\times\ldots\times\mathbb A^m$. The author shows $\overline Y$ is irreducible, but not algebraic set. How can we prove $\overline Y$ is an algebraic set? is this really necessary?

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Arthur But why the author said "$Y$ a closed subvariety of $X$"? Is it better to say "$Y$ closed subvariety of $\overline Y$"?

Comment: I think it is a convention. Could you explain why the closure of $Y$ in $V$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 3):

The closed sets in the Zariski topology are exactly the algebraic sets. Thus, the closure $\overline{A}$ of any subset $A$ of $X$ is always an algebraic set.

Comment: It's true, of course, silly question. Thanks

Comment: But why the author said "$Y$ a closed subvariety of $X$"? Is it better to say "$Y$ closed subvariety of $\overline Y$"?